# Resume the ViewPager auto sliding while open an app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

Hi I am using ViewPager for auto swiping of 10 Text Quotes.When I open a app it starts from IMAGE1.Then it is keep on swiping upto the 10th quote.Let us consider,the viewpager showing 5th quote. Now I close it. When I open the app again it is starts from the first quote. But I need to show 6th Quote.

How do I resume the quote from where I have left before.

**Quote 1:**

[image: Quote1]

**Quote 5:**

[image]

**Quote 6:**

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
int count=0;
int pager_position;
    private void setTime_ToSlide() {
        TextSlideShowAdapter adapter = new TextSlideShowAdapter(MainActivity.this, title1, title2);
        myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.reviewpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);


        Log.e("TEST", "Title Value Main " + title1 + " Title 2" + title2);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (count1 <= 56) {
                            myPager.setCurrentItem(count1);
                            pager_position = myPager.getCurrentItem();
                            Log.e("Get current item", String.valueOf(myPager.getCurrentItem()));
                            count1++;
                        } else {
                            count1 = 0;
                            myPager.setCurrentItem(count1);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 500, 3000);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveCurrentPagePosition();
        Log.e("Get SharedPreference ", String.valueOf(pager_position));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //...
        setCurrentPagePosition();
    }

    private void setCurrentPagePosition() {
        myPager.setCurrentItem(pager_position);
    }

    private void saveCurrentPagePosition() {
        // store current page position in shared preference
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("PagerPosition", pager_position);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

store your page position in sharedpreferences in onPause method and when you come back to app get page value from preferences and use that value to set current item

```
 viewPager.setCurrentItem(postion from preferences);
```

Comment: in your setcurrentPagePosition method replace pager_position by value that you get from shared preferences means         myPager.setCurrentItem(preferences.getInt("PagerPosition",0));@ParamaSudha

Comment: @ParamaSudha also while using shared preference i.e in method saveCurrentPagePosition use this code  editor.putInt("PagerPosition", myPager.getCurrentItem());

Answer (score 1):

As Ajinkya said store the current position of your pager in shared preference in onPause() of your Activity/Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveCurrentPagePosition();
}
```

Fetch the stored position in your Activity/Fragment onResume() and set the current position for ViewPager like

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //...
    setCurrentPagePosition();
}
```

Helper methods -

```
private void setCurrentPagePosition() {
    // fetch from shared prefs or set default as 0
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(postion_from_preferences);
 }

private void saveCurrentPagePosition() {
    // store current page position in shared preference
}
```

Comment: Thank you @vijay_t. I followed ur answer.But have not get it. I have updated with my code.Please check it.